# Bucket Sort Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Assume probability distribution of input is uniform over the range 0 to 100. Goal is to bucket-sort 10,000 real numbers.

1. What is the probability that bucket 0 will be empty?
2. What is the probability that the first 5 buckets will all be empty?

My intuition tells me the first one is 99/100 * 10000 since 0 is the only thing that can fill bucket 0.

The second one would be similar logic but numbers greater than 5.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use exponentiation. In order for bucket 0 to be empty, you must get one of the other 100 (not 99) options for each of the 10000 picks. Since these are independent events, the probabilities of getting another value each time multiply. Similar reasoning applies in the second case.